# Beryllium carbide formation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why does beryllium form carbide of formula $\ce{Be2C}$ and not $\ce{BeC2}$ as the other elements of its group?
I am not able to understand the change in formula of beryllium carbide.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some of your own thoughts.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34099/why-do-different-elements-form-different-types-of-carbides

Comment: There could be a thermodynamic aspect to it: see eg https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34109/16683

Answer (score 13):

Briefly, it's a matter of cationic radii values and crystal packing at given $p, T$. Without referring to the detailed review of the corresponding crystal structures, you can imagine $\ce{M^{II}2C}$ as the derivative of methane $\ce{CH4}$, whereas $\ce{M^{II}C2}$ can be seen as the derivative of acetylene $\ce{C2H2}$. Smaller cation is the best fit for the "richer" tetrahedral coordination environment of carbon, whereas larger cation of the same charge won't be able to do so (sterical hindrance). That's why $\ce{Be2C}$ is the primary carbide of beryllium, $\ce{Mg2C}$ is also [known to exist at higher pressures](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpcc.5b07862), (magnesium, along with lithium, otherwise forms an allene-based $\ce{Mg2C3}$ or $\ce{Li4C3}$ [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbide)), but bulkier cations $\ce{Ca^2+, Sr^2+, Ba^2+}$ only form 1/2-carbides. Aluminium, on the other hand, forms $\ce{Al4C3}$ that hydrolyses to methane. This is a good example of the [diagonal relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_relationship) between $\ce{Be}$ and $\ce{Al}$, and also between $\ce{Li}$ and $\ce{Mg}$.